# Is Running programs by address common?

Tags: console

I have read some of the things posted here and I keep reading about people running stuff like /foldername/executable -cmd NAME

(was reading about a programmer using Eclipse, so he was testing something he made)

I don't see things like that when I run things here (Ubuntu 12.04) because of the launcher and the Ubuntu button at the very top. That and Eclipse indigo has a button for running and testing things it makes.

Just asking how and why it's common?

(assuming it's the Terminal[Ctrl+alt+T] but I'm not sure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all executables are meaningful when run from a GUI; running them from a CLI is the only way to observe what particular executables do and to interact with them.

Comment: Do you mean the possible errors without message boxes? The kind usually printed on the consoles...

If so, I guess I have nothing to worry about. Eclipse has a console output.

If not, please give an example.

Comment: These commands can usually also be run from another program that captures stdout/stderr, such as Eclipse does. But sometimes they use ncurses which Eclipse (probably) can't handle properly.

Answer (score 0):

There is an environmental variable, called PATH. Type `echo $PATH` in Terminal to see its contents. If some applications reside in folders not in list, you must call them by absolute path, like `/opt/games/ponyhunting`. Applications from Software center are always in PATH, but some distribution-agnostic packages from app sites are not.

Comment: The contents of $PATH aren't helpful to me... Example: I have at least Eclipse, zsnes and GIMP. None are in $PATH...

Output: /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

...I find "dir" more helpful. But $PATH is something new to me, at least. Thank you for that.